# Transpose with multiple variables and more than one metrics in R

Tags: r, transpose

I'm previously a SAS user - since I don't have SAS anymore I need to learn to use R for work.
The dataset has the following column:

```
market date sitename impression clicks
```

I want to transpose it into:

```
market date sitename-impression  sitename-clicks
```

I think in SAS I used to do:

```
Proc Transpose
by market date;
id sitename;
var impression clicks;
run;
```

I do have a book on R and googled a lot, but couldn't find the solution that works...

Would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You're looking for `reshape` or something like `cast` or `melt` from the  `reshape` package.  I'm not familiar with SAS so I'm not sure what the output of the function you gave is.  Can you provide a small sample of the input data and the desired output?

Comment: Oh it may be that the poster wants to go from wide to long.  If that's the case disregard my answer.

Comment: @Justin Looking at variable names your suggestion makes the most sense but I'm holding off on editing my answer until the poster provides a data set of what they have and what they expect (or a representation of the data they have)

Comment: @TylerRinker tried to figure out what he wanted, but SAS is inscrutable and I'm technically supposed to be at work... Your answer and the reshape package should be enough to get him started.

Answer (score 4):

Let me start by saying welcome to stackoverflow.  Glad to have anew  user.  When you ask a question it's helpful and encouraged for you to provide the code you're using and a reproducible data set that looks like the original.  This is called a minimal reproducible example.  To get a data set into here you can use several options, here are two: use  `dput()` around the object name and cut and paste what is displayed in the console or just post the dataframe directly.  For the code provide all the code necessary to replicate your problem.  I hope you find this helpful for future questions you'll ask.

I may not fully understand but I think you want to transform, not transpose, the data.

```
dat <- data.frame(market=rnorm(10), date=rnorm(10),   #let's create a data set
    sitename=rnorm(10), impression=rnorm(10),  clicks=rnorm(10))
dat  #look at it (I pasted it below)

 #   > dat                                                      
 #          market        date   sitename impression      clicks
 #   1  -0.9593797 -0.08411994  1.6079129 -0.5204772 -0.31633966
 #   2  -0.5088689  1.78799500 -0.2469315  1.3476964 -0.04344779
 #   3  -0.1527465  0.81673996  1.7824969 -1.5531260 -1.28304384
 #   4  -0.7026194  0.52072913 -0.1174356  0.5722210 -1.20474443
 #   5  -0.4537490 -0.69139062  1.1124277 -0.2452974 -0.33025320
 #   6   0.7466588  0.36318337 -0.4623319 -0.9036768 -0.65754302
 #   7   0.8007612  2.59588554  0.1820732  0.4318629 -0.36308748
 #   8   1.0781715 -1.01512734  0.2297475  0.9219439 -1.15687902
 #   9   0.3731450 -0.19004572  0.5190749 -1.4020371 -0.97370295
 #   10  0.7724259  1.76528303  0.5781786 -0.5490849 -0.83819036

#now to create the new columns (I think this is what you want)
#the easiest way is to use transform.  ?tranform for more        
dat.new <- transform(dat, sitename.clicks=sitename-clicks,   
    impression.clicks=impression-clicks)
dat.new  #here's the new data set.  Notice it has the new and old columns.

#To get rid of the old columns you can use indexing and specify the columns you want.
dat.new[, c(1:2, 6:7)]

#We could have also done:
dat.new[, c(1,2,6,7)]
#or said the columns not wanted with negative indexing:
dat.new[, -c(3:5)]
```

**EDIT** In looking at Brian's comments and the variables I would think that a long to wide transformation is what the poster desires.  I would likely approach it using Wickham's reshape2 package as well, as this method is easier for me to work with and I imagine it would be easier for an R beginner as well.  However, here is a base way to do the long to wide format using the same data set Brian provided:

```
wide <- reshape(DF, v.names=c("impression", "clicks"), idvar=c("market", "date"),
timevar="sitename", direction="wide")

reshape(wide)
```

The reshape function is very flexible but takes some getting used to to use appropriately.  I'm leaving my previous response up as well to keep the history of this post though I now believe this is not the posters intent.  It serves as a reminder that a reproducible example is very helpful in providing clarity to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Example data, as Tyler said, is important. I interpreted your question differently because I thought your data was different. I didn't take the `-` as a literal subtraction of numerics, but a combination of variables.

```
DF <- expand.grid(market = LETTERS[1:5],
                  date = Sys.Date()+(0:5),
                  sitename = letters[1:2])
n <- nrow(DF)
DF$impression <- sample(100, n, replace=TRUE)
DF$clicks <- sample(100, n, replace=TRUE)
```

I find the `reshape2` package useful for these sort of transpositions/transformations/rearrangements.

```
library("reshape2")

dcast(melt(DF, id.vars=c("market","date","sitename")), 
      market+date~sitename+variable)
```

gives

```
   market       date a_impression a_clicks b_impression b_clicks
1       A 2012-02-28           74       97           11       71
2       A 2012-02-29           34       30           88       35
3       A 2012-03-01           40       85           40       49
4       A 2012-03-02           46       12           99       20
5       A 2012-03-03            6       95           85       56
6       A 2012-03-04           61       61           42       64
7       B 2012-02-28            4       53           74        9
8       B 2012-02-29           43       27           92       59
9       B 2012-03-01           34       26           86       43
10      B 2012-03-02           81       47           84       35
11      B 2012-03-03            3        5           91       48
12      B 2012-03-04           19       26           99       21
13      C 2012-02-28           22       31          100       53
14      C 2012-02-29           40       83           95       27
15      C 2012-03-01           78       89           81       29
16      C 2012-03-02           57       55           79       87
17      C 2012-03-03           37       61            3       97
18      C 2012-03-04           83       61           41       77
19      D 2012-02-28           81       18           47        3
20      D 2012-02-29           90      100           17       83
21      D 2012-03-01           12       40           35       93
22      D 2012-03-02           85       14           63       67
23      D 2012-03-03           63       53           29       58
24      D 2012-03-04           40       79           56       70
25      E 2012-02-28           97       62           68       31
26      E 2012-02-29           24       84           17       63
27      E 2012-03-01           94       93           32        2
28      E 2012-03-02            6       26           86       26
29      E 2012-03-03          100       34           37       80
30      E 2012-03-04           89       87           72       11
```

The column names have a `_` between them rather than a `-`, but you can change that if you want. I wouldn't recommend it, though, because then you will have problems later referencing the column since the `-` will be taken as subtraction (you would need to quote the name).